# React -- "ghost" children when using recursive components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a survey with drop-downs whose values determine the next drop-down to be shown. The flow is shown by the flowchart below:

[image]

I am treating this as a graph traversal (of sorts) and using recursive components to handle this. Also, note that the above is a toy example; the real task would have many more decision points and a tree with much more "depth". Therefore, restructuring to use if/else statements is not feasible for the larger task, even if the above example could easily be handled with that.

See the code I'm using below (here's a [link to a sandbox with the same code](https://codesandbox.io/s/recursive-react-dropdowns-2yrqxr)):

```js
const {
  useState
} = React;

function Dropdown({
  node_id,
  props,
  childSetter
}) {
  const defaultOption = {
    value: "select",
    label: "Select an option"
  };
  const options = [defaultOption, ...props.options];
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState(defaultOption.value);

  return ( <
    select key = {
      `dropdown-${node_id}`
    }
    value = {
      selectedOption
    }
    onChange = {
      (e) => {
        const newSelection = options.find(
          (opt) => opt.value === e.target.value
        );
        setSelectedOption(newSelection.value);
        childSetter(newSelection.leads_to);
      }
    } >
    {
      options.map((o, idx) => ( <
        option key = {
          idx
        }
        value = {
          o.value
        } > {
          o.label
        } <
        /option>
      ))
    } <
    /select>
  );
}

function Text({
  node_id,
  props
}) {
  return <p key = {
    `text-${node_id}`
  } > {
    props.text
  } < /p>;
}

const nodes = {
  reason: {
    node_id: "reason",
    type: "dropdown",
    preamble: < p > I was unsatisfied because < /p>,
    props: {
      options: [{
          value: "food",
          label: "the food wasn't cooked well",
          leads_to: "recommendation"
        },
        {
          value: "impolite",
          label: "the staff was impolite",
          leads_to: "recommendation"
        },
        {
          value: "ambiance",
          label: "the ambiance wasn't what we wanted",
          leads_to: "recommendation"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  recommendation: {
    node_id: "recommendation",
    type: "dropdown",
    preamble: < p > How likely are you to recommend others to visit us ? < /p>,
    props: {
      options: [{
          value: "1",
          label: "1",
          leads_to: "terminal"
        },
        {
          value: "2",
          label: "2",
          leads_to: "terminal"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  terminal: {
    node_id: "terminal",
    type: "text",
    props: {
      text: "Thank you for your submission."
    }
  }
};

function Node({
  node_id,
  type,
  preamble,
  props,
  nodes
}) {
  const [activeChild, setActiveChild] = useState(undefined);
  const selfComponent = {
    dropdown: ( <
      Dropdown node_id = {
        node_id
      }
      props = {
        props
      }
      childSetter = {
        setActiveChild
      }
      />
    ),
    text: < Text node_id = {
      node_id
    }
    props = {
      props
    }
    />
  }[type];
  const childNode = nodes[activeChild];
  return ( <
    div id = {
      `node-${node_id}`
    }
    className = "node" > {
      preamble
    } {
      selfComponent
    } {
      childNode && ( <
        Node node_id = {
          childNode.node_id
        }
        type = {
          childNode.type
        }
        preamble = {
          childNode.preamble
        }
        props = {
          childNode.props
        }
        nodes = {
          nodes
        }
        />
      )
    } <
    /div>
  );
}

function App() {
  return ( <
    div className = "App" >
    <
    Node node_id = {
      "root"
    }
    type = {
      "dropdown"
    }
    preamble = { < p > Were you satisfied with our services ? < /p>}
      props = {
        {
          options: [{
              value: "satsified",
              label: "Yes",
              leads_to: "recommendation"
            },
            {
              value: "unsatisfied",
              label: "No",
              leads_to: "reason"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
      nodes = {
        nodes
      }
      /> <
      /div>
    );
  }

  ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
  ).render( <
    App / >
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

This setup mostly works. However, if the user has already traversed the graph to a given depth and then changes one of the parent nodes, there are "ghost" children that shouldn't be there.

[image: "Ghost" children]

However, choosing the default option ("Select an option") does work as expected and removes all children.

Additionally, changing the value of one of the parents doesn't reset the immediate child to its default state (i.e., "Select an option") and retains the value from the previous selection.

[image: Children don't reset]

How can I solve these issues?

Comment: Give these nodes a `key` prop. Also, if the code cannot be run, don’t paste it in a code snippet. Just format it as a code block.

Comment: @Terry Thank you for the clarification. I've updated the code snippet and it works correctly now. I used the snippet instead of a code block so the 100+ lines of code could be collapsed and not overwhelm the reader.

Comment: @Terry Thank you, your suggestion for adding a key solves the first problem (the "ghost" children). Any suggestions on solving the second problem (i.e., when a parent's selection/state changes, reset the immediate child -- the children drop down retains its selected value at the moment).

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is the problem here is the activeChild is not changed for the child components because of the useState.

If you try to `console.log(childNode)` in the `Node` component, you will find that even though you've changed to uppermost node, the `activeChild` remains already selected in the components below - and because of that, its children also do not change.

Adding the following piece of code in the `Node` component seems to fix that for me.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setActiveChild(undefined);
  }, [node_id])
```

Whenever the node ID changes, the children are reset.

[Sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/recursive-react-dropdowns-forked-j35k99?file=/src/App.js)

Edit: Typos

Comment: Thanks! This solves the "ghost children" problem from the first GIF. However, the problem from the second GIF (i.e., if a change to the parent would yield the same "type" of node, that child retains its selected value; I'd like for the child to be reset to "select an option" instead. Any ideas on how to achieve this?